# I want to create list from dictionary elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have Nested dictionary something like this.

```
{'A': {'21-26': 2,
  '26-31': 7,
  '31-36': 3,
  '36-41': 2,
  '41-46': 0,
  '46-51': 0,
  'Above 51': 0},
 'B': {'21-26': 2,
  '26-31': 11,
  '31-36': 5,
  '36-41': 4,
  '41-46': 1,
  '46-51': 0,
  'Above 51': 3}}
```

And I want to create list by key from second dictionary.
And i don't want duplicates in my list.

Required Output is

`ls = ['21-26','26-31','31-36','36-41','41-46','46-51','Above 51']`

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use pandas? IF so:

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'A': {'21-26': 2, '26-31': 7, '31-36': 3, '36-41': 2, '41-46': 0, '46-51': 0, 'Above 51': 0}, 'B': {'21-26': 2, '26-31': 11, '31-36': 5, '36-41': 4, '41-46': 1, '46-51': 0, 'Above 51': 3}}

pd.DataFrame(a).index.to_list()
```

output:

```
['21-26', '26-31', '31-36', '36-41', '41-46', '46-51', 'Above 51']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
>>> list(set(key for val in d.values() for key in val.keys()))
['21-26', '36-41', '31-36', '46-51', 'Above 51', '26-31', '41-46']
```

Where `d` is your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Simple set comprehension, then convert to list. `a` is your dict.

```
list({k for v in a.values() for k in v.keys()})
```

Output ordering is random, but you can sort how you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chain.from_iterable()` to chain inner dictionaries and `dict.fromkeys()` to remove duplicates:

```
from itertools import chain

c = chain.from_iterable(dct.values())
result = list(dict.fromkeys(c))
```